# Thymeleaf use parameters as string

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am switching from freemarker to thymeleaf and am trying to learn it a little bit.

Currently the problem I am faced with is that thymeleaf doesn't allow me to use parameters as a string. So for example in freemarker I could do this

```
<#if keywords??>
    <meta name="keywords"
          content="${keywords}">
</#if>
```

This would check to see if keywords variable exists and then if it does it would put value of keywords into content. How would I do this in thymeleaf?

I know I can check if variable exists with

```
<meta th:if="${keywords != null}" name="keywords">
```

But how do I put content of keywords into content?

Or for example in freemarker I could do

```
<#include "/pages/"+file+".ftlh">
```

In thymeleaf I understand that I can do something along lines of

```
<div th:replace="/pages/index.html :: index"></div>
```

but what if I want to access a variable called `file` and inject those values into something like

```
<div th:replace="/pages/${file}.html :: ${file}"></div>
```

Another example is if let's say I have a paragraph.

hello ${username} how are you doing today?

How do I insert value of username there? I understand that I can do so by doing

hello  how are you doing today?

Is this really the only way?!

Thanks for any clarification. I can't seem to find any article explaining how to do what I mentioned above. Coming from freemarker, these things seem like something thymeleaf should have too.

Comment: I don't understand your question: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#variables

Comment: And this for the replace https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#parameterizable-fragment-signatures

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I am trying to understand how I can use variable as a string and insert it anywhere that I would like to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really is pretty basic Thymeleaf (all explained in the docs).  For keywords (attributes):

```
<meta th:if="${keywords != null}" name="keywords" th:content="${keywords}">
```

For paragraph text (traditional):

```
<p>Hello <span th:text="${username}" /> how are you doing today? </p>
```

or with inlining

```
 <p>Hello [[${username}]] how are you doing today? </p>
```

Replacing the contents of files is a little bit trickier, but the same syntax:

```
<div th:include="~{${'/pages/' + file + '.html'} :: ${file}}"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This is exactly what I wanted to learn!!! And it was very educational too!!!